# How to define either/or trait bounds in rust

Tags: recursion, rust, traits

I have the following marker trait and some definitions:

```rust
trait HasProperty<P> {}

struct Property1;
struct Property2;

struct WithProperty<P, Tail> {}
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```rust
fn check::<P, T>(token: T) where T: HasProperty<P> {}

fn test() {
  let token1 = WithProperty<Property1, WithProperty<Property2, ()>>;
  let token2 = WithProperty<Property1, ()>;

  check::<Property1>(token1); // should compile
  check::<Property2>(token1); // should compile
  check::<Property1>(token2); // should compile
  check::<Property2>(token2); // should fail with "WithProperty<Property1, ()> does not implement HasProperty<Property2>"
}
```

However I do not understand how to implement the trait conformance for `WithProperty`. The following does not work because of overlapping trait definitions:

```rust
impl<P, Tail> HasProperty<P> for WithProperty<P, Tail> {}
impl<P, P2, Tail> HasProperty<P> for WithProperty<P2, Tail> where Tail: HasProperty<P> {}
```

I found the following in Yew which solves the same problem, but I cannot wrap my head around how this works: https://github.com/yewstack/yew/blob/master/packages/yew/src/html/component/properties.rs.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the `yew` solution it might be best to ask the compiler to dump the macro-expanded AST. That way you can see exactly what the generated structs and traits are.

I don't know if this is exactly how this works in `yew`, but something like this works, and maybe some of the ugly bits can be hidden in macros:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait HasProperty<P, How> {}

struct Property1;
struct Property2;

struct WithProperty<P, Tail>(PhantomData<P>, Tail);

fn with<P, Tail>(t: Tail) -> WithProperty<P, Tail> {
    WithProperty(PhantomData, t)
}

fn check<P, How>(token: &impl HasProperty<P, How>) {}

struct Directly;
impl<P, Tail> HasProperty<P, Directly> for WithProperty<P, Tail> {}

struct Step<N>(N);
impl<P, P2, Tail, N> HasProperty<P, Step<N>> for WithProperty<P2, Tail> where Tail: HasProperty<P, N> {}

fn main() {
  let token1 = with::<Property1, _>(with::<Property2, _>(()));
  let token2 = with::<Property1, _>(());

  check::<Property1, _>(&token1); // compiles
  check::<Property2, _>(&token1); // compiles
  check::<Property1, _>(&token2); // compiles
  // check::<Property2, _>(&token2); // fails with "the trait bound `(): HasProperty<Property2, _>` is not satisfied"
}
```

The two `HasProperty` implementations are not overlapping since they are implemented for two different `struct`s. The `Step` is a (linked-list-like) wrapper indicating that the property exists, and is found `N` steps into the `WithProperty` nesting.

If you write something like:

```rust
with::<Property1, _>(with::<Property2, _>(with::<Property1, _>(())))
```

Then the `check` call complains about multiple possible `impl`s. I don't know if `yew` handles this more gracefully.

Comment: Hi @aurel-bílý, thank you so much for giving this example. I did expand the code, but there is a lot to parse there and the solution is not as straightforward as your example, I assume mostly to improve error handling. The point where I struggled was how to use the `How` parameter, as it is never supplied. I understand now that this parameter is always inferred, correct?